# i had my electrical panel replaced and i noticed afterwards they put in a 150-amp rated panel. but i have 200 amps service

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

[image]Why would the electrician put in a 150-amp rated panel if i have 200-amp service. And is that legal. Is this a common practice? And is this up to code? I live in Florida.

[image]

Comment: You may actually have a meter main with the 150A panel technically a subpanel. Please upload pictures of: *meter and any stuff next to it*, *the 150A panel*, *any subpanels you have, if any*. There may be far more going on than you realize. 200A panels are dirt cheap, so your panel is likely 200A rated with a 150A breaker, but there are many unknowns.

Comment: On the invoice it says 150 amp surface indoor top quality cutler hammer/QO panel.

Comment: not sure how to upload a photo

Comment: Click edit below your post, click in the body box where you want the pic in relation to text, in the icon box above text click the square icon with mountains and moon.

Comment: The invoice is meaningless. Because Cutler Hammer is one type of panel (Eaton's better quality panel) and QO is another (Square D's better quality panel) so they would have picked one to install. It may well be that 150A is also meaningless, possibly really meaning "150A or above". So we need to see what you actually have installed to figure this out.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the panel labels.

Comment: What is the number on the handle of the main breaker there?  Is there a breaker out at the meter, and what's the number on its breaker handle?

Comment: on the main breaker inside the panel 200. I don't see any breaker outside.

Comment: @RonaldPekarskiSR can you get us photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel cabinet sides please?

Answer (score 2):

Based on pictures and comments, you've got a 200A Square D QO panel. The invoice said 150A Cutler Hammer or QO. I think the invoice is, for better or worse, a generic "heavy up *whatever*" statement that means "we'll put in *at least* 150A panel of *one of* these two major good quality types of panels".

It may be that this company does so many heavy-ups that barring extras like solar hookups they just have a few boilerplate prices - 150A-250A CH/QO, maybe <150A CH/QO, maybe 250A+ CH/QO (i.e., for the class 320/400 double 200A panels) and maybe a low-ball BR/Homeline price when they're hungry.

It seems a little odd to me for electrical because there are so many variables. But sometimes easier than keeping track of all the little details. Similar to when I had a hot water tank replacement last year - I sent them pictures, they sent me an all-inclusive flat price, and they didn't itemize the expansion tank, fittings, valves, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's a 40 or 42 space QO panel.  Wouldn't be out of place in the Tesla Gigafactory, as it's one of two industrial-tier panels in the consumer market (the other being Eaton CH aka Cutler Hammer).  And they went for the largest number of spaces generally available at sane cost, which is what we recommend.

Square D doesn't make 40/42s with 150A busing. I don't think anyone does, because it would be a separate SKU and an odd duck product that no distributor would want to stock, only to save 40 cents a unit of copper or a nickel of aluminum.  Panels of this size generally have 200A or 225A busing.

If you're after solar, that'll give you 40A or 70A of solar, respectively.

I don't know why they wrote 150A+ given their intentions of giving you this panel.